# How can I use the equals method to compare an array of objects in a different class

Tags: java, arrays, object, equals

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean result = false;
        if (obj instanceof Recipe) {
           Recipe that = (Recipe) obj;
            if(this.getName().equals(that.getName())){

            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < I.length; cnt++) {
                if (I[cnt].getName().equals(that.getName())) {

                result = (this.getName() == that.getName());
        }
             }
    }
    }
    return result;

}
```

I can compare the name of the recipe and once they are equals I need to compare one by one the ingredients but I do not know how to do the comparison. I know I need a for loop which I added it to compare all the ingredients, but what to do after that. I would really appreciate any type of help.

Comment: I'd add the recipe's ingredient lists into sets since ingredients can be in any order.

That said, just because two recipes have the same ingredients doesn't mean it's the same recipe, so I'm wary of this from a real-world standpoint. Waffles and pancakes use the same ingredients, for example. You need to identify what you mean by recipes being "equal".

Comment: what is I?    is there an array? where it us defined?

Comment: Ingredient[] I = new Ingredient[10]; I is an array of ingredients.

Comment: Post the defintion if Recipe. there must be ingredients as part of Recipe, so is that a field?

Answer (score 0):

override equals() in Recipe, as it looks you are trying,

then you have to compare each field of Recipe

But you shoul post the source of the fields of Recipe

Comment: The recipes have to have equal names to continue with the process. It does not matter if they have different names.

Answer (score 0):

The List equals checks for references to equal objects in the same order, which may be what you need. If so, consider Arrays.asList which gives you a List view of an array of references.